# need help with IE 6

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i've been working on a website now for like a couple months and i test it on chrome mainly. but before i release anything big i always check it on firefox 3.something and IE7. Now i've received some complaints that that it doesn't look very good in IE6 and when i do check it... well ya it doesn't look like its supposed to. Is there any quick fix that i can add to my HTML to make it look the same in IE6 as it does every where else?

Comment: No magicians here... wanna post some of the HTML that's causing it to look "broken"

Comment: I saw the title of this one and thought, "yeah, don't we all?"

Comment: "quick fix", lol, good one - IE6 is np-hard

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of downvotes:  have you tried adding IE6 to your test matrix?  If you have a significant number of users complaining that it looks bad on IE6, you clearly have a significant number of users using IE6 to use it, so it seems like it would be worth your while to just add it to the set of browsers you check before release.  Just sayin'.

Comment: I upvoted because I agree but I think there is a good argument for educating your users about why they should upgrade and giving them some gentle nudging. As you say though, it does depend upon your target audience.

Answer (score 2):

A really good start is http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/   Just place it in conditional comment tags in the head of your document and it will make ie6 'standards-compliant'.  After that make sure you have seperate css documents for each version of IE, and make sure all of your code is valid with w3's validator.  Also declaring a doctype can fix many issues, but it MUST be on the very first line that the browser sees.

Edit: also, for png transparency, I've found that this http://www.twinhelix.com/test/ (IE PNGFIX 2.0 Alpha) works best.

Comment: IE7.js (now IE8.js, I believe) is pretty great, but bear in mind that a) it doesn’t fix all issues, and b) it won’t work for users who have JavaScript turned off.

Answer (score 1):

There is no quick trick to getting everything to work.  Pretty much have to examine each element that looks different.
That said, you might try looking at a CSS reset file.
[Yahoo has one.](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)
And if you [search google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=css+reset&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=css+reset&fp=KqtEvp1-d7s) I'm sure you can find others.

Answer (score 1):

Read this: [Internet Exporer box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug). Also try using YUI reset or Eric Meyer's resetReloaded to set a baseline for all your styles.

And stop developing in Chrome! Try Firefox with Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

How badly does your website 'break' in IE6? If it's minor, then I wouldn't worry about it.

How critical is it that it works in IE6? It's [share of the market](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) is slowly but surely declining (Looking at my own logs from a Government website also shows that IE6 is definitely going away). Can you display a message on your website letting users know if they use IE6 and advising that they upgrade?

There are many reasons to upgrade, and educating your users as to why they should upgrade might also be worthwhile?

Comment: Thankfully we got permission to dump IE6.. especially when we pointed out that MS was saying stop using IE 6 http://www.businessinsider.com/microsoft-launches-anti-marketing-campaign-for-ie6-2011-3

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... if there is a simple solution I really want to know it. :)
But you can anyway use [this](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/features/Default.aspx?key=webpreview) good Microsoft tool to cross-test your pages.
It can be usefull for compare the final render of a website.

Answer (score 0):

CSS resets will probably do nothing if it looks fine in IE7.  Things like double margins when floating and overflow:auto bugs are things that need to be manually added for each occurance.  I'd suggest adding the following line to your head tag:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><style type="text/css">@import "/stylesheets/ie6.css";</style><![endif]-->
```

and then writing an ie6.css file to fix all the bugs (yes, one at a time)

Probably not what you wanted to hear, but it is why everyone hates IE6 so much

Answer (score 0):

you can check version of client browser and include css fixing for that browser. but most simple solution is to show an alert or notification to client that his browser is outdated and provide links to download latest browser

here are some way to show that notification

http://garmahis.com/tools/ie6-update-warning/

i like this solution

http://www.browser-update.org/